# HTML table formatting when implementing Bootstrap in Flask

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pandas

So I used pandas to create a table from a csv file, and load that .html table to localhost right now with flask. I just started using bootstrap to help with some css and adding some navbars, but when I add bootstrap css sheets my table formatting becomes a little weird.

Before: [image: before]

After: [image: after]

My issue is that the table loses some spacing on the left; it becomes very tight and you can't see the left border.

If anyone knows how I can fix this please let me know

Comment: add .table class to table tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the Bootstrap styles by adding an inline `style="margin-left: 15px;"` to your `<table>` tag like this:

```
<table style="margin-left: 15px;">
  <tr>
   <td>Cell 1</td>
   <td>Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```